# Hybris: Change default boost value

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, solr-boost

I want to show products of a particular manufacturer always on top. I tried applying boost rule from backoffice. But even after applying boost rule, the products don't appear on the top, instead somewhere below. This is probably because the boost factor is not enough.

The default boost factor is set as 100. Is there any way to change this value from backoffice or somewhere else?

Comment: Do you run a Solr indexing after creating new boost rules ?

Comment: Hi @Benoit! Applying boost rule from backoffice didn't require solr indexing. After applying boost rule, my favorite category position is hiked up in search results as compared to without any boost rule. But it still doesn't appear at top as desired. So I wanted to somehow try applying a bigger boost value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a property "maxBoostFactorValue" defined for bean "boostRuleValidator" in the commercesearch-spring.xml. By modifying this value, the max boost factor can be changed.